# The non flat module $\mathbb{Z}/m$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

A general result states that an $R$-module $M$ is flat if and only if $I\otimes_R M \simeq IM$ for all ideals $I\subset R$. However, there is something I don't understand.

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}$, and let $M = \mathbb{Z}/m$. Then, for any ideal $I = n\mathbb{Z}$, it seems to me that
$$IM = n\mathbb{Z} \cdot \mathbb{Z}/m\simeq n (\mathbb{Z}/m)$$
and that
$$I \otimes_\mathbb{Z} M = n\mathbb{Z} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}/m = \mathbb{Z} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} n(\mathbb{Z}/m) \simeq n(\mathbb{Z}/m).$$
What is my mistake? I mean, I'm aware of that $\mathbb{Z}/m$ is not flat...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've written makes no sense unless $n$ is a divisor of $m$. The correct statements are
$$IM=n\mathbb{Z}\cdot \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}=\gcd(n,m)\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$$
and because $I\cong \mathbb{Z}$,
$$I\otimes_\mathbb{Z}M\cong\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}M\cong M=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$$
which are only isomorphic when $\gcd(n,m)=1$. Since for any $m>1$ there is some $n$ with $\gcd(n,m)>1$, the module $M$ is not flat.

(I also suggest you get in the habit of writing out quotient $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ in full, with the second $\mathbb{Z}$.)

Comment: But why does $I\simeq \mathbb{Z}$ imply that $I\otimes_\mathbb{Z} M \simeq \mathbb{Z} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} M$?

Comment: If you give the elements of something different names and get a fundamentally different answer then something is clearly wrong - the whole point of isomorphisms is to preserve all important strucutre.

Comment: More concretely, if $f\colon I\to \mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism, then the map $\phi\colon I\otimes_\mathbb{Z}M\to \mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}M$ defined by
$$\textstyle\phi\left(\sum i_\alpha\otimes m_\alpha\right)=\sum f(i_\alpha)\otimes m_\alpha$$
is an isomorphism.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just confused. Say that $I = m \mathbb{Z}$ (i.e., $m=n$ in my question). Then, the elements of the tensor product should by generated elements of the form $mz_1\otimes[z_2]$, right? Where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are integers. But then isn't $mz_1\otimes[z_2] = z_1\otimes m[z_2] = z_1\otimes [m z_2] = z_1\otimes 0 = 0$?

Comment: The relevant rule for elements in a tensor product $M\otimes_R N$ is that for any elements $m\in M$, $n\in N$, and $r\in R$, we have$$r(m\otimes n)=(rm)\otimes n=m\otimes(rn)$$
If you look at, say, $(2\mathbb{Z})\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}$, this means that for any integer $r$, 
$$r(2\otimes 1)=(2r)\otimes 1=2\otimes r$$
but you **can't** pull out the $2$. (Note that $1$ isn't even an element of $2\mathbb{Z}$!) However in the tensor product $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}$, you **can** do
$$2\otimes 1=(2\cdot 1)\otimes 1=2(1\otimes 1)=1\otimes2$$
because $1$ **is** an element of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Ah, such a stupid mistake I made. Thanks for the patience and the answer!